# Access and modify property(ies) of an Application-Scoped Managed Bean from Session Listener

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I need to access an application-scoped managed bean to modify certain properties from within an HttpSessionListener.

I already used something like the following:

```
@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    HttpSession session = se.getSession();
    User user = userService.findBySessionId(session.getId());    

    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

     ApplicationScopedBean appBean = (ApplicationScopedBean) externalContext.getApplicationMap().get("appBean");

     appBean.getConnectedUsers().remove(user);
}
```

externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext() causes a null pointer exception here already, and even if it didn't I'm not sure appBean could be accessible the above way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe your page is not using the FacesServlet. Show your web.xml JSF servlet configuration and mapping and the full name of the page.

Comment: seems that it's not possible to get the FacesContext using FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() from a HttpSessionListener; just like it's not possible to do so from a Servlet. Maybe if you can get the ServletContext you can do something like getServletContext().getAttribute("appBean");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FacesContext` is only available in the thread serving the HTTP request initiated by the webbrowser which has invoked the `FacesServlet`. During a session destroy there's not necessarily means of a HTTP request. Sessions are usually destroyed by a background thread managed by the container. This does not invoke a HTTP request through the `FacesServlet`. So you should not expect the `FacesContext` to be always there during the session destroy. Only when you call `session.invalidate()` inside a JSF managed bean, then the `FacesContext` is available.

If your application scoped managed bean is managed by JSF `@ManagedBean`, then it's good to know that JSF stores it under the covers as an attribute of the `ServletContext`. The `ServletContext` in turn is available in the session listener by [`HttpSession#getServletContext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getServletContext%28%29).

So, this should do:

```
@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    HttpSession session = se.getSession();
    User user = userService.findBySessionId(session.getId());    
    ApplicationScopedBean appBean = (ApplicationScopedBean) session.getServletContext().getAttribute("appBean");
    appBean.getConnectedUsers().remove(user);
}
```

If you're running a Servlet 3.0 capable container, an alternative is to just let your application scoped bean implement `HttpSessionListener` and register itself as such upon construction. This way you have direct reference to the `connectedUsers` property.

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class AppBean implements HttpSessionListener {

    public AppBean() {
        ServletContext context = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
        context.addListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        HttpSession session = se.getSession();
        User user = userService.findBySessionId(session.getId());    
        connectedUsers.remove(user);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Again another alternative is to keep the `User` in the session scope as a session scoped managed bean. You can then use the `@PreDestroy` annotation to mark a method which should be invoked when the session is destroyed.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class User {

    @ManagedProperty("#{appBean}")
    private AppBean appBean;

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        appBean.getConnectedUsers().remove(this);
    }

    // ...
}
```

This has the additional benefit that the `User` is in EL context available as `#{user}`.