# How to access JSF application-scoped managed beans from an HttpSessionListener?

Tags: jsf

I am running a **JSF** application and have declared some application-scoped backing beans (either in **common-beans.xml** or using the  `@ManagedBean`  and  `@ApplicationScoped`  annotations).

How can I access these beans from inside a `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener`  ?

I understand that the  `FacesContext`  is not available in the session listener so using:

```
public class AnHTTPSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    ...
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent e) {
        AppBean appBean = (AppBean) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                                                .getExternalContext()
                                                .getApplicationMap().get("appBean")
       ...
    }
```

... threw a NPE as expected.

#### UPDATE:

*(before BalusC answer)*

What I ended up doing was declare the application-wide information I needed to access in **web.xml** using **env-entry** elements (instead of using application-scoped beans) and then retrieve that information using:

```
   InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
   Context env = (Context) ic.lookup("java:comp/env");
   appName = (String) env.lookup("appBeanValue");
```

It's not what I had in mind but it's a workaround.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JSF stores application scoped managed beans as attributes of the [`ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html).

So, this should do:

```
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent e) {
    AppBean appBean = (AppBean) e.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("appBean");
    // ...
}
```

#### See also:

- [Get JSF managed bean by name in any Servlet related class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112/jsf-get-managed-bean-by-name/2633733#2633733)
- [Access and modify property(ies) of an Application-Scoped Managed Bean from Session Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603357/access-and-modify-propertyies-of-an-application-scoped-managed-bean-from-sessi/10605191#10605191)